# Entity Framework Core: Get all entities of given type (EntityType)

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to copy all entities of one DbContext to another DbContext.
I am able to list all Entity types  by using the Model.GetEntityTypes() method of the source DbContext.
How can I retrieve all entities of the given type from the source context, in order to add them to the destination context?

Comment: Does `OfType<T>` work here? I haven't tried it myself. It may only work with LINQ-to-objects.